# Print to PDF From RDP on OSX

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, pdf, printing

I have a MacBook that conects tru Remote Apps/Remote Desktop to a windows 2008 Server. The printers are redirected with no problems. The problem is the PDF printer.

I want to be able to save from the Remote APP to my desktop the Print Job as PDF. The OSX PDF printer does not redirect. How can i achive this? I dont mind using apps to  do so, its just dont know any in Mac systems.

Thanks for taking a look.

- Millz

Comment: Just try installing a PDF printer for OSX, as you mentioned. Here's a link to some options (Top google result for "PDF Printer OSX") https://pdf.wondershare.com/pdf-editing-tips/pdf-printer-mac.html

Comment: Macs have native PDF, they don't need some dodgy Wondershare application to enable it. The problem is the Windows pdf printer presumably - as Windows needs 3rd party software to support pdf... Though I will admit, the question as it stands is somewhat confusing.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help.
Tetsujin, i now about the Mac ative PDF, but when you do a Remote Session, that PDF "printer" is not redirected. so you cant print to PDF. I assume thats because the native PDF is not actualy a printer. Hope i wans't confusing this time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to need something capable on the remote machine. It's not a problem I've ever really tackled as it's just never cropped up before. There's a whole slew of methods here & they claim it's now built into Windows too, it just needs enabling - http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/print-pdf-windows/

Comment: @Tetsujin I also think that a true third-party PDF printer is needed on the Mac side here. The built-in PDF "printer" is great, but this technically not a PDF printer (e.g. it doesn't appear nowhere in the installed printer list)

Comment: @PierU - the Mac's native display format is PDF. It doesn't need a printer emulator to do this. If one was added it would be as a courtesy to Microsoft… which Apple are usually not really inclined to do, so yes, it would have to be a 3rd party. I'd be inclined to ask the MS RDP team about it. They're usually pretty responsive, I've had them add features before now - except they're also unlikely to be interested in supporting a Server OS that went EoL over 2 years ago. They'll probably say "Oh, that works on the latest version, you'll have to update" etc...

Comment: @Tetsujin it doesn't have to come from MS. Even if I never needed one, I can see that there are many third-party PDF printers for macOS: I would give a try with one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but i have the exact same problem. The thread is too old but i guess it might help some one
https://github.com/rodyager/RWTS-PDFwriter

what we actually need is to add a virtual pdf printer on mac for it to be visible in rdp windows session.

the above link might help others

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. I know this is frustrating to not be able to comment below 50 points reputation, but this is the rule here...